# Flutterr bloc, how to log event changes?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have code that log state changing in console for me, code looks like this.

```
class ApplicationBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Change change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    log('stateChange(${bloc.runtimeType} ${change.currentState})');
  }

  @override
  void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    log('onError(${bloc.runtimeType}, $error, $stackTrace)');
    super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
  }
}
```

I also need to log events, that users may start in application, how i can do it ?

i want it to look like this

```
log('stateChange(${bloc.runtimeType}, event ${something that show event } started. State is ${change.currentState})');
```

Answer (score 2):

use `onEvent` callback:

```
    @override
    void onEvent(Bloc bloc, Object? event) {
        super.onEvent(bloc, event);
        log(...)
    }
```

More info about possible callbacks here:
https://pub.dev/documentation/bloc/latest/bloc/BlocObserver-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the [BlocObserver](https://pub.dev/documentation/bloc/latest/bloc/BlocObserver-class.html) class.

Create a new file:

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'dart:developer';

class GlobalBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onEvent(Bloc bloc, Object? event) {
    super.onEvent(bloc, event);
    log('${bloc.runtimeType} $event', name: 'Test log');
  }

  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Change change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    log('${bloc.runtimeType} $change', name: 'Test log');
  }

  @override
  void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {
    super.onTransition(bloc, transition);
    log('${bloc.runtimeType} $transition', name: 'Test log');
  }

  @override
  void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
    log('${bloc.runtimeType} $error $stackTrace', name: 'Test log');
  }
}
```

and in your `main.dart`:

```
void main() {
  Bloc.observer = GlobalBlocObserver();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

That's it!